# how can I replace an empty value in a cell by a value from an other cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I Would like to do 3 simple things :
1/ check if a cell in the column N is empty.
2/ If it is, I would like to set in the cell N the value of the cell Q of the same line
3/ I wan't to turn this N cell into red

I'am facing two problems :
1/   A1.createTextFinder("") wont accept ("") as a value describing an empty cell
2/  I don't know how to call the value of the column Q from the same line as the N empty cell.

here is the code I find and start to modify

```
function STARTDATE() {
  var PROsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("0_LISTE PROJETS");
 

  var A1 = PROsheet.getRange("N3:N");
  A1.createTextFinder("").replaceAllWith("Q");
}
```

I also use on a different spreadsheet a code to delete line when the column A have an empty cell. I guess this code can be easy to modify from "delete line" to "copy the value from an other row", but I haven't been able to understand how it works so far...
if it is possible, I would like the solution to be based on this code more them on the other one, because I think it can help me to go deeper in my understanding to see different fonction based on the same type of code

the code itself :

```
function myFunction() {
  
  var PLsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PLANNING_DATA");
  

  let rows = PLsheet.getDataRange();
  let numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  let valuesdelete = rows.getValues();

  let rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
  let row = valuesdelete[i];
  if (row[0] == "")

    {
      PLsheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
    rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }


}
```

thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function replaceMTSinNwithvalueInQ() {   
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("PLANNING_DATA");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,14,sh.getLastRow() - 1,4).getValues();
  let bs = sh.getRange(2,14,sh.getLastRow() - 1).getBackgrounds();
  let o = vs.map((r,i) => {
    if(r[0] === "") {
      bs[i][0] = "#ff0000";//color backgrounds in red
      return [r[3]];//set value 
    } else {
      return [r[0]];//set value
    }
  })
  sh.getRange(2,14,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o).setBackgrounds(bs);
}
```